# how to print automatically using php

Tags: php

Hey I am trying to print a text using php.
This print should occur automatically. Now I am testing in normal HP deskjet printer but in future it prints through thermal printer.
Now my code is

```
<?php
$printer = "\\\\LOCALHOST\\HP Deskjet 1510 series";
$fp = fopen($printer, "w");
$data = "hello";
fwrite($fp,$data);
```

This code runs fine with no error but no printing occurs.

printing status is like below
[image]

please help..

Comment: This would require PHP access to the user's local system.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code.

```
<?php
$printer = "\\\\LOCALHOST\\HP Deskjet 1510 series");
if($ph = printer_open($printer))
{   
   $data= "Hello";
   printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
   printer_write($ph, $data);
  printer_close($ph);
}
 else "Couldn't connect...";
?>
```

Comment: i get an error Fatal error: Call to undefined function printer_open()

Comment: do you have a php_printer.dll enabled?  Use this link for downloading the file http://www.dlldll.com/php_printer.dll_download.html 

and   in your php.ini file -> add the following : printer.default_printer=PHP_INI_ALL extension=php_printer.dll

Comment: The libray php_printer.dll must be loaded in your server(wamp or any other) in order for the above code to work. try restarting server. makesure to load correct libray based on your php version see here http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/printer/0.1.0-dev/ for more dlls for several php versions.

Comment: I have xampp and  php_printer.dll loaded into C:\xampp\php\ext folder..
then I write the printer.default_printer=PHP_INI_ALL extension=php_printer.dll  at the end of php.ini file.. but error remaining same

Comment: hey i configure this dll. when i run this code then no error occured.
But print not happening